# fetching data and show in view page

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

> when i execute while loop in view page this below error show
>   Message: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

my model

```
function get_row($id) {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('pending_list');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

my controller

```
public function pass_print() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

    $data['h'] = $this->admin_model->get_row($id);
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('sidebar');
    $this->load->view('print_pass',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

my view

```
<?php while($rows= mysql_fetch_array($h)){?>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                                                Visitors Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" value="<?php $rows['visitor_name']?>" name="visitor" placeholder="Visitors Name">
                                            </div>                                            
                                        </div>
<?php}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Model: You are defining "select" function in Model which is not calling in the controller

```
function select() {
$this->db->select("emp_name,department");
$this->db->from('employee');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

In Controller: You need to put all the get rows information into a variable named "$h". replace $data['h'] with $h.

```
public function pass_print() {
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$h = $this->admin_model->get_row($id);
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('sidebar');
$this->load->view('print_pass',$data);
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

In View: Used the foreach loop in place of while loop which gives the right result.

```
<?php foreach($h as $data){?>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Visitors Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" value="<?php $data['visitor_name']?>" name="visitor" placeholder="Visitors Name">
</div>                                            
</div>
<?php}?>
```

Comment: you're welcome. if you find the answer useful, please upvote it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

View part is wrong. It' should be

```
<?php
foreach ($h as $item) {
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
            Visitors Name
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" 
            value="<?php echo $item['visitor_name']?>" name="visitor" placeholder="Visitors Name">
        </div>                                            
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

---

if you pass the data to view `$this->load->view('print_pass',$data);` with this then the array name `$data['h']` you have mentioned can only call in VIEW. In your case its `h`

---

Doubt on your code is

in controller you calling `$data['h'] = $this->admin_model->get_row($id);` But model code you have added is have `function select()`. Make sure you're calling correct model method/function

Comment: sorry mistakenly i post the model select() but now i edit my model above.

Comment: @dipti any update ? if works please mark it has green

Answer (score 0):

For model, you can write this instead:

```
$this->db->get_where('pending_list', array('id'=>$id))->row();
```

And for view, use this code to get its value:

```
echo $h->visitor_name;
```